# PowerShell first index of a letter in a string

Tags: powershell

I have a string which will have an unknown quantity of non-alphabetical characters. I would like to remove these from my string. I want everything to the right of the first occurrence of a letter.

e.g.

'3434 34^%43 346&*^& 8 645 Stuff' becomes 'Stuff'

'345$65556&5$&9MoreStuff' becomes 'MoreStuff'

'34*^$76$::^5{][][65And EvenMoreStuff 123! But ItBeganWithA Letter' becomes 'And EvenMoreStuff 123! But ItBeganWithA Letter'

Using PowerShell 5.1

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ``$string.IndexOf('[^a-zA-Z]')``  
``$string -match '^[a-zA-Z]'``

Comment: Please add your existing code to your question.

Comment: ``$string.IndexOfAny('[^azAZ]')`` is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex to remove any leading non-letter characters:

```
'3434 34^%43 346&*^& 8 645 Stuff' -replace '^[^\p{L}]*'
```

Pattern describes:

```
^          # start of string
[^\p{L}]*  # 0 or more characters that are not letters (\p{L} == unicode category "letters")
```